# Can we use Instagram for Oauth2 login for normal, business, and creator accounts?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

The current state of using Instagram for Oauth2 login for mobile/web apps is not clear to me.

The old Oauth system appears to be no longer accepting new apps. The new `Instagram Basic Display API` also states explicitly:

> You can't use the API to create user accounts or log your app users into your app
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/

It appears that the minimum scope is `user_profile`, but when I try to use that scope I get an invalid scope error that does not reflect the requested scopes.

`{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid scope: []"}`

It appears that there is also extensive requirements for accessing this API like submitting a passport photo. The documentation also makes it sound like `Instagram Basic Display API` will not work with business or creator accounts, making it sound as if the API is now fragmented.

And finally there are Instagram Testers for sandbox accounts under Roles... but when you select an account it says "accountname (pending)" and provides no instructions for how to accept an invite, and if you visit instagram.com/developers with the test account and click "Sandbox invites" there is nothing there, and the user does not receive any kind of email.

Can anyone shed light on the current status of using Instagram for Oauth2 for the purposes of authenticating login into a mobile/web app?

Other reading: https://community.auth0.com/t/instagram-login-is-deprecated-and-the-documentation-on-auth0-is-broken/24122/20

Comment: AND just that you know! With the Basic API you are not allowed to use it for authentification. You need to use the Facebook Login. And plus to that, the user token you receive is only hour valid...

Comment: I've had no problems oauthing with the new instagram api and 1 hour token is pretty common. That said I'm not looking for refresh tokens because I hand that responsibility off to Firebase. Are there no refresh tokens?

Comment: It says in the docs: `Data returned by the API cannot be used to authenticate your app users or log them into your app. If you need an authentication solution we recommend using Facebook Login instead.`. To refresh the token you need to redirect the user again to Instagram.

Answer (score 3):

For the Tester Invite:

1. Login to Instagram on a desktop
2. Click the person icon on the top right-hand side
3. Click the Cog icon next to Edit Profile
4. Select Authorized Apps in the popup
5. Select Tester Invites tab
6. Click Accept for your app

Once you accept the tester invite, the invalid scope error will hopefully go away.